# Modulo equation, retrieve K from d

Tags: algorithm, math, modulo

Here's an equation:

```
d is the multiple inverse of 3 modulo K.
```

Assuming I have d, can I find K?

Also, K is not necessarily prime.

Thanks!

Comment: and what you tried so far?

Comment: I've tried brute force, with different d's. I can't find any patterns that occur over and over, which is quite disturbing. Perhaps i'm missing some number's theory lemma or some other Group's algebra rule.

Comment: How about `K = 3*d - 1`?

Comment: This really has nothing to do with programming, it is suitable for math.stackexchange.com not here.

Comment: I agree with @AliAmiri, this is not an algorithm question, since it doesn't actually discuss an algorithm; it's a math question all the way.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it a purely mathematical question and belongs at [math.se]

Answer (score 1):

You know that

```
d*3 = 1 (mod K)
```

this means

```
d*3 = 1 + n*K
```

independently of `K` this however means

```
d*3 = 1 (mod n)
```

i.e. that `d` is the inverse of 3 modulo `n` too, thus the answer is in general not unique (actually you can use any divisor of `nK` as answer).

Comment: Yes, this is correct. The question is a result of a different question regarding RSA Algorithm. I have m=(p-1)(q-1), p,q are primes s.t N=pq. e is relatively prime to m, i.e gcd(e,m)=1 (makes sense because e=3), d is the multiple opposite of e modulo m. So the question was assuming e=3 and I get a hold of d, I need to show that I can factor N (that is find q,p). So i thought, if I could find m via e(3) and d, I can easily find p,q and solve it. Perhaps there's another way to factor N?